# Post messages from async threads to main thread in F#

Tags: .net, powershell, f#, system.reactive, f#-async

There is a subscription to an observable that sends out log messages. Some of the log messages come from other threads because they are are in F# async blocks. I need to be able to write out the messages from the main thread.

Here is [the code](https://github.com/ctaggart/Paket/blob/66e3fcdddd755313bf492f2528f0042c6b825c66/src/Paket.PowerShell/CmdletExt.fs#L45-L56) that currently filters out many of the log messages because they are not on the main thread:

```
member x.RegisterTrace() =
    Logging.verbose <- x.Verbose
    let id = Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
    Logging.subscribe (fun trace ->
        if id = Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId then
            match trace.Level with
            | TraceLevel.Warning -> x.WriteWarning trace.Text
            | TraceLevel.Error -> x.WriteWarning trace.Text
            | _ -> x.WriteObject trace.Text
        else
            Diagnostics.Debug.Write(sprintf "not on main PS thread: %A" trace)
    )
```

I have various forms of using `System.Threading.SynchronizationContent` `.Current`, `.SetSynchronizationConent`, `.Send`, `.Post`. I've also dabbled with `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`. I've also tried `Async.SwitchToContext`. No matter what I do, `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` ends up being different and PowerShell complains. Am I going about this wrong?

Here is the work-in-progress [pull request](https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/pull/875) and more details about [the problem](https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/issues/874).

UPDATE 2015-06-16 Tue 11:45 AM PST

@RCH Thank you, but using `Async.SwitchToContext` to set the `SynchronizationContext` does not appear to work. Here is the code and debugging output when I do `Paket-Restore -Force`:

```
member x.RegisterTrace() =
    let a = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
    Logging.verbose <- x.Verbose
    let ctx = SynchronizationContext.Current
    Logging.subscribe (fun trace ->
        let b = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
        async {
            let c = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
            do! Async.SwitchToContext ctx
            let d = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
            Debug.WriteLine (sprintf "%d %d %d %d %s" a b c d trace.Text)
        } |> Async.Start
    )
```

[image: Debug Output]

An expert at work recommended another solution that I'm going to try that involves passing in the context when subscribing.

UPDATE 2015-06-16 Tue 5:30 PM PST

I got help creating an [IObservable.SubscribeOn](https://github.com/ctaggart/paket/compare/powershell...SubscribeOn) that allows the SynchrnonizationContext to be passed in. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem eithe, but may be part of the solution. May be a custom SynchronizationContext is needed like that [SingleThreadSynchrnonizationContext](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx). I would love help making one, but before I do that, I'm going to try out System.Reactive's `Observable.ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)`.

UPDATE 2015-06-16 Tue 8:30 PM PST

I haven't been able to get Rx to work either. `Scheduler.CurrentThread` [doesn't behave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408341/observeonscheduler-currentthread-doesnt-cause-subscribed-action-to-be-run-on) the way I was hoping. I then tried out [these changes](https://github.com/ctaggart/paket/compare/powershell...rx) and the callback doesn't get called.

```
member x.RegisterTrace() =
    Logging.verbose <- x.Verbose
    let a = Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
    let ctx = match SynchronizationContext.Current with null -> SynchronizationContext() | sc -> sc
    let sch = SynchronizationContextScheduler ctx
    Logging.event.Publish.ObserveOn sch
    |> Observable.subscribe (fun trace ->
        let b = Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
        Debug.WriteLine(sprintf "%d %d %s" a b trace.Text)
```

A custom SynchronizationContext may be what is needed. :/

Comment: Ah, finally. Should have thought about that from the beginning: Console applications do not have a SynchronizationContext, so SynchronizationContext.Current is always null. -> see edited answer.

Comment: Yes, if having Rx as a new dependency is not an issue, that'd be my preferred way too. Instead of having `Event`, Rx also provides very convenient `Subject`s.

Comment: I think I can add the dependency to Paket.PowerShell, but not Paket.Core. Unfortunately, it is also not working. I published my attempt.

Comment: I hacked together a `QueuingSynchrnonizationContext`. I'm sure it can be simplified. It queues any of the messages not on the same thread and prints them out at the end. There has got to be a better/immediate way, but may be that is another question. https://github.com/ctaggart/paket/compare/powershell...queuing

Comment: Great, glad it worked out in the end! Until someone comes up with a better way, I could at least suggest some minuscule improvements to the `QueuingSynchronizationContext`: https://gist.github.com/rasch/f55d5205730f97e32932

Comment: I like those improvements and will use them in my next iteration of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating an `EventSink` that has a queue of callbacks that are executed on the main PowerShell thread via `Drain()`. I put the main computation on another thread. The [pull request](https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/pull/875) has the full code and more details.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For UI applications (Forms, WPF, F# interactive, ...) selecting `SynchronizationContext.Current` and `Async.SwitchToContext` from your trials as well as borrowing some code from *Paket* is enough.

*For console applications, however, there is no SynchronizationContext and thus no thread the continuations can be `Post`ed to, so they will end up on the thread pool.* A possible workaround is found on [MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2015/02/18/10259049.aspx).

**Solution for UI applications only:**

Having

```
module Logging

open System.Diagnostics

type Trace = { Level: TraceLevel; Text: string }

let public event = Event<Trace>()

let subscribe callback = Observable.subscribe callback event.Publish
```

and

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module CmdletExt

open System.Diagnostics
open System.Threading

type PSCmdletStandalone() =
    member x.RegisterTrace() =
        let syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current
        Logging.subscribe (fun trace ->
            async {
                do! Async.SwitchToContext syncContext
                let threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
                match trace.Level with
                | TraceLevel.Warning -> printfn "WARN (on %i): %s" threadId trace.Text
                | TraceLevel.Error -> printfn "ERROR (on %i): %s" threadId trace.Text
                | _ -> printfn "(on %i): %s" threadId trace.Text
            } |> Async.Start // or Async.StartImmediate
        )
```

then, registering on the main thread

```
#load "Logging.fs"
#load "SO.fs"

open System.Diagnostics
open System.Threading
open System

(new PSCmdletStandalone()).RegisterTrace()

printfn "Main: %i" Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId

for i in Enum.GetValues(typeof<TraceLevel>) do
    async {
        let workerId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
        do Logging.event.Trigger { Level = unbox i; Text = sprintf "From %i" workerId }
    } |> Async.Start
```

yields e.g.

```
Main: 1
WARN (on 1): From 23
(on 1): From 25
ERROR (on 1): From 22
(on 1): From 13
(on 1): From 14
```

Comment: If you want me to, I can transform that this evening (CEST) into a pull request for your branch.

Comment: Thank you @RCH. Unfortunately, it does not appear to work when applied. I responded above with more details.

Comment: @CameronTaggart that looks interesting. Thanks for the update. I will try to reproduce that here, from the looks I'd never have expected `a, b, c, d` to be all distinct.